# Can not bind 'this' to imported function - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, import, module, this

I am a beginner and I want to bind 'this' to helper-functions which I have imported from an other file (that I can use the variables, I created in the current lexical environment ).

But I have recognized, that I can bind these imported functions to any object - which I have created in the file, into I have imported them - but not to the current this.

node.js example: 
https://github.com/sdeli/issues-with-this

```js
// random-js-file.js

// this is the function I import in app.js
function logOutThis() {
    console.log(this);
}

module.exports = logOutThis;
// --------------------------------

// app.js
const importedFn = require('./random-js-file.js');

// this is now the global of random-js-file.js
importedFn();
console.log('--------------------------------');

var monkey = {
  chimp : 'chimp'
}

// this is now the object 'monkey'
var myfunction = importedFn.bind(monkey);
myfunction();
console.log('---------------------------------');

//this should be now the current this
var myfunction2 = importedFn.bind(this);
myfunction2();
// console.log displays '{}' and i can not refer to the variable in this lexical environment
```

So I dont understand why I can not bind 'this' into a function which I have imported but I can bind it to any object.

Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: #1: by importedFn.bind(this) you are passing the global context to `random-js-file` 's export ? #2: you might want to check if the local variable that you are checking is declared somewhere later in the codebase and therefore undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to access the inner context of an imported module unless it explicitly exports the bits you want (or provides functions that expose them). Javascript `this` doesn't behave like Java `this`, and modules aren't classes.

There's some other cases, but basically, if the function you're currently is called `someFunc` and it was called with syntax `a.someFunc()`, then `this` will be the same as `a`. Here's a worked example:

```
const someObject = {
    someFunc() {
       //Here, "this" will be the same as someObject, because of the way we called it
       someOtherFunction();

    }
};

someObject.someFunc();

function someOtherFunc() {
    //"this" is still someObject because it's inherited from the calling function which was not called using a method syntax
    x.y(); //inside the y() function, "this" will now be x
}
```

Basically, IMHO, `this` is a broken mess in Javascript and is one of the key reasons I avoided using it whereever possible. That means I don't use classes, and I get everything I need from closures.

Comment: I hope this explanation is clear - if not, let me know and I'll have another go!

Comment: Thanks Duncan for your answer it was enough clear, I really appreciate it.

Comment: So the real thing I am struggling with is, that I want to keep my clone clean. 
But when I need to nest functions deeper than one level, than the code gets really like spagetti

So can I ask you how do you deal in your code with the situation, when you have lets say some main functions and those have helper-functions and some of the helper functions have additional helpers as well. And so your code would have 3 layer of functions.

Thanks a lot for your answer and i am really thankful if you can put me into the correct direction.

Comment: It's not uncommon to have a lot of layers of functions with helper functions - most medium-large applications will have nested functions (i.e. functions that call functions) at least 6 or 7 deep, sometimes more. To make this managable, I recommend:
 * using powerful libraries where you can (e.g. lodash, moment)
 * getting comfortable with ES6 language features (Array.map() etc)
 * giving your functions good, descriptive names
 * decoupling your low-level functions so they can be re-used easily
 * organising your files in a sensible structure

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.. it was really helpful